# Why cant I increment this value

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code

```
int const *p = new int(5);
printf("%d",(*p)++);
```

Now it says that

`error C3892: 'p' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const`

Why am I getting this error ? I understand that p is a constant however I am simply trying to print (*p)++ which is 6 not increment the content in the address that p points to. Could anyone explain to me what actually is happening ?

Comment: Read-only variables are not assignable

Comment: You are incrementing the content not the pointer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operation `(*p)++` is syntactically equivalent to `(*p) += 1`. That is, it attempts to do an assignment to the original variable. The compiler is complaining because you're not allowed to modify `const` variables.

In this case, you've declared `p` to be a pointer to `const`, rather than a `const` pointer.

Instead, try `printf("%d", (*p)+1);`

Alternatively, you could declare `p` as a `const` pointer: `int * const p`, but that would increment the value pointed to by `p`.

Answer (score 3):

Change it this way:

```
int* const p = new int(5);
```

This means the pointer is constant.

```
int const *p = new int(5);
```

This means that what the pointer is pointing to is constant.

If you do it the first way, then you can increment the value you are pointing to by the pointer.

(*p)++ is dereferencing the pointer and incrementing the value. So you should the first way I posted.